# Mapping multiple values from the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I have to get text value using value id from another table
Table 1 contains value ids and table 2 contains name and value ids

Table 1 =

```
|SEVERITY | OCCURENCE | DETECTABILITY|
|2        |     3     |       4      |
```

Table 2 =

```
id|name     |value|
1 |Very High|5
2 |High     |4
3 |Moderate |3
4 |Low      |2
5 |Minor/Minimal|1
```

RESULT REQUIRED

```
SEVERITY | OCCURENCE | DETECTABILITY|
Low    |     Moderate    |       High     |
```

Comment: Your tables have some design problems.

Comment: You would normally use the id, not the (redundant) 'value' for mapping. After that it's just a case of joining and aliasing table 2 several times, once for each attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly agree with @Strawberry comment, you should have used `table2.id` as foreign key in your `table1`. Because join based on `value` might lead to multiple mappings if there are duplicate records with same `value`.

That being said, if you've unique `value` in `table2` then you can do as follow.

```
SELECT 
    sev.`name` AS SEVERITY,
    occ.`name` AS OCCURENCE,
    det.`name` AS DETECTABILITY
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 sev ON table1.SEVERITY = sev.`value`
LEFT JOIN table2 occ ON table1.OCCURENCE = occ.`value`
LEFT JOIN table2 det ON table1.DETECTABILITY = det.`value`;
```

**Note**: We've used `LEFT JOIN` to make sure if we don't have value of any of the column mentioned in `table1` we should still be able to fetch records.

If you are sure that these 3 columns will always have value than you can also use `INNER JOIN`.